# How do you filter students in class by school?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I'm currently using Microsoft Graph Api to create Schools and Classes. One class can be linked to multiple schools and the same class can have multiple students from different schools. How can i filter the students in a class by school?
I tried to use Odata query with $expand parameter and $filter parameter without success like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/classes/{classId}/members?$expand=schools($select=id)&$filter=school/id eq '{schoolId}
```

It's seems that is not supported. There is any chanche that it will be supported in the future?
How to achieve that kind of filter on the ressource at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to start with `/schools` rather than `/classes`.

For example, you can expand the members of each Class in a School using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/schools/{schoolId}/classes?$expand=members
```

You can also look up the members of a single class using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/schools/{schoolId}/classes/{classId}?$expand=members
```

Comment: Thank you. I have just one more question: in a specific class I have more than 1k members. If I retrieve members from the `/education/classes/{classId/members` endpoint, the `@odata:nextLink` property is used while using the $expand parameter on school endpoint everything is retrieved at once. Do you think that this could cause problems when there are a lot of members in a class?

Comment: `$expand` will only return a limited number of records due to the lack of paging. If you have large membership lists, you will need to make multiple calls to the API: 1) Retrieve the list of Classes for a given School, 2) Retrieve the Members for each of the Classes. You can optimize this a bit using [JSON Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) and requesting membership for up to 20 classes per call.

Comment: Say I have two schools: schoolA and schoolB. They both have some students registered in classX. Using the endpoint that you suggest (`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/schools/{schoolA}/classes/{classX}?$expand=members`), I expect to retrive only students from schoolA but I get all students (schoolA and schoolB).
Is this the normal behaviour or a bug ?

Comment: Since both Students and Classes can technically belong to 2 different schools, this is expected behavior. In many cases, it is better to have two different Classes so members/assignments/chats/files/etc. are distinct between schools. This is a common scenario for certain subjects (Music and Art being the canonical examples).

Comment: The problem is that I manage an application shared by multiple schools The classes are axactly the same for all schools. Since we have roughly 100 schools and 100 classes, it means I should create about 10k classes per session. It is very inefficient.Will it be possible in the future to filter the members of a class just by their school? I need to know that before deciding to use microsoft education api and integrate it with our internal applications.

Comment: By school do you mean individual school or distinct school districts?

Comment: I mean individual school.

Comment: Unless they share the same Teacher, they should really be distinct Classes or you are likely to see a lot of confusion between Teachers (Team Owners) and Students (Team Members). FWIT, a large number of classes/groups wouldn't be unusual for a school district with 100 schools (I'd expect even more actually).